# Is the sum of positive jumps from a jump process adapted again?

Tags: stochastic-processes, step-function

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\{\mathcal F_t\}_{t\in [0;T]},\mathbb P)$ be a filtered probability space satisfying the usual conditions and let $\{X_t\}_{t\in[0;T]}$ be an adapted stochastic process, whose paths are right-continuous step functions with finitely many steps. As usual, $\Delta X_t := X_t - X_{t-}$ and write $X_{0-} := 0$. Define
$$
Y_t
:= \sum_{s \in [0;t], \Delta X_s > 0} \Delta X_s.
$$

Is $Y$ necessarily adapted and how can I prove that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I think that I proved that $Y$ is adapted. We define $\tau_k$ as the time of the $k$-th jump ($\tau_0 := 0$). This is equivalent to the recursive definition
$$
\tau_{k+1} := \inf \{ t \in (\tau_k;T] | X_t \ne X_{\tau_k} \}.
$$
To prove that $\tau_{k+1}$ is a stopping time, note that
$$
\{ \tau_{k+1} > t \}
=
\{ \tau_k \ge t \}
\cup 
(
 \{ \tau_k < t \}
 \cap \{ \forall s\in(\tau_k;t] \colon X_s = X_{\tau_k} \}
)
$$
and
$$
\{ \forall s\in(\tau_k;t] \colon j_s = j_{\tau_k} \}
=
\bigcap_{s \in (\mathbb Q \cap [0;t)) \cup \{t\}} (
 \{ \tau_k \ge s \}
 \cup \{ X_s = X_{\tau_k \wedge t} \}
)
\in \mathcal F_t.
$$

Now
$$
Y_t
=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1_{\{\tau_k \le t\}} \max(0,\Delta X_{\tau_k \wedge t}).
$$